# How does python's map work with several arguments

Tags: python, built-in

I have this code:

```
def funky_fun(lst):
    tmp = list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, lst[1:], lst[:-1]))
    print('check:', tmp, lst[1:] + lst[:-1])
    return [lst[0]] + tmp + [lst[-1]]

print(funky_fun(funky_fun([1])))
```

Here `funky_fun([1])` returns `[1, 1]`, while the second call (`funky_fun([1, 1])` returns `[1, 2, 1]`.

Do you understand why? Because `lsr[1:]` is `[1]`, and `lst[:-1]` is also `[1]`, so I would think it would print `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, but `tmp` is `[2]`.
It probably has something to do with the map function that I don't understand.

Comment: `lst[1:]` is not `[1]` it is `[]`

Comment: @Netwave Nah it's `[1]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, https://repl.it/repls/FlashyBluePullet ,  Im missing something

Comment: @Netwave She's talking about the second call there, where `lst` is `[1, 1]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, i missed that then haha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is no longer relevant but here is the answer: The `lst` slices are the iterables whose elements will be used as arguments for the function passed to `map` in order to construct a new iterable with the results. Here you're pairing up `[1]` and `[1]` whose elements when added yield `2` (you're not actually adding the lists, you wouldn't need `map` for that). Similarly `list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,[1,2],[3,4]))` would yield `[4,6]`